# How to match strings that contain neither A nor B using Java Regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm a newbie to Java regular expressions. My apologies if you find this question really simple..But I've seen some similar questions and tried those answers, neither worked.

I'm trying to match strings that have a pattern 'Words outside parenthesis ( word )', There could be several choices for the stuff within the parenthesis, but I want to exclude some of them. In other words, strings that don't contain some words within the parenthesis should be matched.

e.g. If I don't want A or B to be within the parenthesis,

```
 words outside parenthesis ( C )  // should match
 words outside parenthesis ( A )  // should not match
 words outside parenthesis ( B )  // should not match
```

where A and B could be word or phrase. But they won't appear together (There is no way that the pattern 'AB' appears within the parenthesis).

I've tried:

```
    .+\(\s*(?!A|B)\s*\)
```

and

```
    .+\(\s*^/(?!A|B)\s*\)
```

and

```
    .+\(\s*(?!\bA\b)(?!\bB\b)\s*\)
```

However, neither of them worked. Please help! Thanks!

**EDIT**:

Maybe I didn't clarify myself. A or B could be word or phrase, which means A could be the word 'hello', B could be 'hello world' and I don't want 'hello' or 'hello world' to be matched. So [^AB] won't work for my case because that would become [^hellohello world].

Comment: can there be nested parenthesis?

Comment: `(?!A|B)` only checks that something isn't followed by `A` or `B` but wouldn't match on `C` automatically. There lies the problem.

Comment: @RohitJain, No. There won't be nested parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that after doing the negative lookahead `(?![^AB])` you don't match on the words just before the closing `)` with a `\w+` or `[^)]+` like

```
.+\(\s(?!(nomatch|false)\b)\w+\s\)
```

*Sample Matches:*

```
words outside parenthesis ( match )  // matches
words outside parenthesis ( true )  // matches

words outside parenthesis ( nomatch )  // doesn't match
words outside parenthesis ( false )  // doesn't match
```

Comment: Terrific! Thank you very much for not only providing the correct answer and also pointing out what I did wrong. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex pattern with `Matcher#find()` method:

```
\\([^)]*(?:A|B)[^)]*\\)
```

If the `find()` method returns `true` for this pattern even once, then your string is not a valid match.

The trick is to find the pattern that shouldn't be matched. And if the pattern is found, then your string is not valid. This is easier to achieve.

```
String[] arr = { "words outside parenthesis ( A )", 
                 "words outside parenthesis ( B )",
                 "words outside parenthesis ( C )" 
               };

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\([^)]*(?:A|B)[^)]*\\)");

for (String str: arr) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(str + " => is not a valid match");
    } else {
        System.out.println(str + " => is a valid match");
    }
}
```

Replace `A` and `B` with your required words. If there are more words, then append them to alternation operator.

Comment: +1 This is a good approach as well if capturing the +ve match is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :
`String myPattern = "^.*\\([^AaBb]\\)$";`

`^.*` = can start with any character, or even no character.

`\\([^AaBb])\\$` = not ending with (A), (a), (B) or (b).

Comment: This won't work because OP wants to negate on words not characters.

Comment: Oh! I didn't understand that. It doesn't work in that case indeed.